# Architectural approach in iOS Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, interface-builder

Would you code this design mockup below as tableview with sectioned groups that are padded on the sides with custom cell types or would you put the groups in a scroll view and make each section a built up UIView.

This isn't an opinion based question or "to general" this is an iOS development design problem.

In Interface-Builder I have seven screens that look like the image below. If I use a tableview for the scrolling and used grouped sections those sections should not be able to scroll they need to be static for lack of a better word. Is that even possible?

The sections headers will stick at the top until you scroll past them which isn't what I want.

I can't put a static un-scrollable table in a scrollview either since that is just backwards and wrong. Also with this approach I have different sized headers for each section and different cell types for each section. Seems rather tacky/hacky to do this.

If I use the UIView build up approach thats a lot of building since there are 7 screens that have this look.

What is the better decision based on a native iOS development approach? Better to use a lot of custom TableViews for each screen or a bunch of UIViews with subviews? Both approaches have major trade-offs to me which is unusual in my experience. Do you see a better approach then what I'm going after?

[image]

Comment: How many rows can it have?

Comment: It varies from a minimum of 3 up to 5 not including the last row for "other" where they can type in a answer.

Comment: You could probably make a UIView subclass that does exactly what you want more easily than use a table.  That subclass would dynamically add in UIView subclasses for the rows you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using tables, when you want a radically different look, is that you often find yourself fighting against it.  At some point, you might even try to write code that subverts the public API and goes and manipulates underlying views in the cell or tableview.

While this is "acceptable" and not considered a "private API", you will probably find that a future iOS version breaks this behavior.

When I want something that is way off table behavior, I don't use a table.

In your case, you can just not use sections and make the headers another cell type.  That probably wouldn't be too bad.  The rest of your mock-up looks like it would be implementable as a table.

Comment: yeah the design choice seems like it could break easily in the future that is a good point. I needed a sanity check on this. Your advice did just that. Thanks Lou.